# How do I get VSTS to find my NetCore unit tests with net Net Standard Azure Functions?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions, .net-standard

I have a build pipeline setup in VSTS that keeps reporting it cannot find my unit tests. The project is a NET Standard Azure Function (V1) but the tests are NET Core. I have tried updating the path to ..\netcoreapp2.0*.test*.dll but it still does not find the tests. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share how does your pipeline in VSTS look like?

Comment: Use NuGet -> NuGet Restore -> Build VS Solution -> VS Test -> Publish Test Results -> Publish Symbols -> Publish Artifact. Where the Test Assemblies field is **\$(BuildConfiguration)\*test*.dll
!**\obj\**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your pipeline correctly, I believe you're using incorrect step for testing .NET Core project.

In one of my solution I have following pipeline:
[image]

As you can see, there's a separate step for "traditional" unit tests and the new ones written in .NET Core. The selected step looks like this:
[image]
Thanks to this I am able to run my tests without any issues.